# Alternating between reading and writing repeatedly

Tags: c++, fstream

My objective is to read a file line by line, check if that line contains some number, and if so rewrite that line. Then continue reading the file.
I've successfully been able to do this for one line, but I can't figure out how to continue reading the rest of the file.
Here's how I replace one line (every line is a known fixed size):

```
while(getline(fs, line)){
  if(condition){
    pos = fs.tellg();       //gets current read position (end of the line I want to change)
    pos -= line.length()+1;    //position of the beginning of the line
    fs.clear();             //switch to write mode
    fs.seekp(pos);          //seek to beginning of line
    fs << new_data;         //overwrite old data with new data (also fixed size)
    fs.close();             //Done.
    continue;
  }
}
```

How do I switch back to read and continue the getline loop?

Comment: To fix this would take more characters than I'm willing to write right now. Your approach is totally wrong. The `fs.close()` is obviously incorrect but there is a more fundamental problem that you can't just "replace" lines in-place like this. And I don't know where you heard that `fs.clear()` "switches to write mode"; it most certainly does not.

Comment: closing within a while loop will prevent further reads. Replace close with flush.  Also continue at the end of a block is superfluous, comment it out and see if there is any difference in behaviour.

Comment: You want basically `grep -w number a > b ; mv b a`

Comment: Additionally, if the file does not end with a newline character, "line.length()+1" will be wrong, and this will clobber the newline character before the last line. And if the file is non-empty, but does not have any newline characters at all, this will be undefined behavior. This will also, apparently, get it wrong on technically-flawed operating systems that use a multibyte sequence to represent a logical newline -- I'm bored, I'd like to start a flame war, let's go!

Comment: @Barry: The code I posted is for overwriting one line. I'm trying to change it to overwrite multiple lines.

Comment: @Sam: when i insert data into this file it's appended with endl, so it's guaranteed to have a newline after every line. I'm open to any suggestions though.

Comment: @ringø yes exactly, but without having to rewrite / replace the entire file.

Comment: Unless ALL your entries in the file are exactly identical length, and the same number before/after, you can't reliably rewrite into the file you're reading from (at least not with standard C or C++ functionality). Use two files. That's what everything sane does.

Comment: @Mats all entries are identical lengths. New data will be padded with spaces to a fixed size. Anything larger than the fixed size will be rejected. Or  padded with zeroes if the entry is a number.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, TB-scale files and I wanted to modify some header information in the beginning of the file.
Obviously one has to leave enough room when one initially creates the file for any new content, because there is no way to increase the file size (besides appending to it) and the new line has to have the exact same line length as the original one.

Here is a simplification of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool CreateDummy()
{
  ofstream out;
  out.open("Dummy.txt");
  // skip: test if open

  out<<"Some Header"<<endl;
  out<<"REPLACE1  12345678901234567890"<<endl;
  out<<"REPLACE2  12345678901234567890"<<endl;
  out<<"Now ~1 TB of data follows..."<<endl;

  out.close();

  return true;
}


int main()
{
  CreateDummy(); // skip: test if successful

  fstream inout;
  inout.open("Dummy.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
  // skip test if open

  bool FoundFirst = false;
  string FirstText = "REPLACE1";
  string FirstReplacement = "Replaced first!!!";

  bool FoundSecond = false;
  string SecondText = "REPLACE2";
  string SecondReplacement = "Replaced second!!!";

  string Line;
  size_t LastPos = inout.tellg();
  while (getline(inout, Line)) {
    if (FoundFirst == false && Line.compare(0, FirstText.size(), FirstText) == 0) {
      // skip: check if Line.size() >= FirstReplacement.size()
      while (FirstReplacement.size() < Line.size()) FirstReplacement += " ";
      FirstReplacement += '\n';

      inout.seekp(LastPos);
      inout.write(FirstReplacement.c_str(), FirstReplacement.size());
      FoundFirst = true;
    } else if (FoundSecond == false && Line.compare(0, SecondText.size(), SecondText) == 0) {
      // skip: check if Line.size() >= SecondReplacement.size()
      while (SecondReplacement.size() < Line.size()) SecondReplacement += " ";
      SecondReplacement += '\n';

      inout.seekp(LastPos);
      inout.write(SecondReplacement.c_str(), SecondReplacement.size());
      FoundSecond = true;
    }

    if (FoundFirst == true && FoundSecond == true) break;
    LastPos = inout.tellg();
  }
  inout.close();

  return 0;
}
```

The input is

```
Some Header
REPLACE1  12345678901234567890             
REPLACE2  12345678901234567890             
Now ~1 TB of data follows...
```

The output is:

```
Some Header
Replaced first!!!             
Replaced second!!!            
Now ~1 TB of data follows...
```